# Is there a way to get a gem's version before running bundle install (from Gemfile.lock)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I want to get a Gem's version without running bundle install.
Which is to say I want figure out what version bundle is planning to install without actually installing the gem. 
Say read it from the Gemfile.lock(and Gemfile) combined.

Is there a way I can resolve what version bundler plans to install?

I need this because I want to cache the expensive installs while running docker build.

Gems like rails(nokogiri) take a while to install and I would like to do gem install rails -v ... in a previous step before running bundle install.

For this purpose i need to get the rails version before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default if no version is specified in the Gemfile, running `bundle install` will attempt to install the latest version of the gem which is compatible with the rest of the gems and ruby version in your project.  This will create a Gemfile.lock file if one doesn't already exist.  If a Gemfile.lock file is already committed to git repo, it should then install the versions specified in Gemfile.lock.  The point of bundler is to handle dependencies to insure your stack works correctly.

To see the version of a gem bundler is currently using you can run

```
bundle show rails
```

You will probably want to specify the ruby version in the Gemfile for example

```
ruby '~> 2.5'  #
```

You can specify exact version of a gem in the Gemfile like this which you should be able to rely on to be the version bundler will install so long as it's compatible with the rest of the stack. `bundle install` will throw errors if there are incompatible gem versions.

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.11' # this will always install only this version.
```

You may also use pessimistic operator `(~>)` to set for only minor updates

```
gem 'influxdb', '~> 0.6.1' # could go to 0.6.2 but never 0.7.0
```

You can also set minimum versions like this although it's probably  not what you need for your question.

```
gem 'pg_query', '>= 0.9.0'
```

If you have a Gemfile.lock already in your repo you can see which version would be installed by running for example:

```
gem show rails
```

Which would show you the version and weather it or not it is currently installed.

For more info see `bundle --help`

Answer (score 1):

If you add a new gem to your gemfile, but don't do `bundle install`, it doesn't install yet. Instead, you can run `bundle lock`, which generates a new lock file. This includes the gem version of the new gem that would be installed.
By running `bundle show new_gem`, it shows it isn't actually installed.

To be sure maybe get a backup of the original `Gemfile.lock` before running the command though.